# Syntax for adding an image to a post

Tags: bug, editor, images, image-upload

One of the syntaxes for adding an image is

```
![two muppets][1]
```

---

But when we add an image using the option provided in the editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>), the syntax is like this,

```
[![two muppets][1]][1]
```

with an extra pair of brackets (costing 5 bytes) which can be deducted because the image works perfectly without those,

```
[][1]
```

So why are they added? Is it intended or a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The additional brackets make the image itself a clickable link to take you to a page containing the full resolution version of the image.  Try to mouse over the images.

For example: image auto inserted with the full `[![Screenshot][1]][1]` syntax.

[image: Screenshot]

Same but with the outer brackets removed: `![Screenshot][1]`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Didn't knew that... Nice...